# convert factor to date without producing NA's

Tags: r

First I'd like to point out that other questions asked in stackoverflow couldn't bring me to the right answer. Since I'm not allowed to comment on any questions, I'm doing this entry right here.

```
head(mw1)
       Datum  Schluss
 1 19.07.2010 1.089,31
 2 19.07.2010 1.093,51
 3 19.07.2010 1.088,38
 4 19.07.2010 1.110,10
 5 19.07.2010 1.117,45
 6 19.07.2010 1.129,74
```

Note that `mw1$Datum` is a factor and if I want to transform it into a date by running `as.Date(mw1$Datum)`, the follwoing error occurs:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

According to other questions asked here, a possible solution might be:

```
mw1$Datum <- factor("19.07.2010")
as.Date(mw1$Datum, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

However, it only produces NA's instead of proper dates.
I would be delighted if someone could help me out with this problem!

Best
targa

Comment: Please re-check your `format`.

Comment: I also tried capital y but this doesn't solve the problem (in case you are referring to it)

Comment: You need: `format = "%d.%m.%Y"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this only produces "2010-07-19" for every observation instead of NA's

Comment: What were you expecting? That is what `mw1$Datum` is equal to, all of its values.

Comment: Well, my goal is to have proper dates. Am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far! I'm afraid, it's all kinda worthless if my "core" problem is not solved, i.e. how I get a proper date vector. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, all the 'ideas' are already provided in the comments. Please, do take your time to study `?as.Date`, including the examples.

Comment: From what I understand the problem was in actually putting the converted date vector back into an object / the original data frame. Please correct me if I'm wrong, @targa.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it step-by-step.

### Step 0: Create dataframe

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Datum  Schluss
1 19.07.2010 1.089,31
2 19.07.2010 1.093,51
3 19.07.2010 1.088,38
4 19.07.2010 1.110,10
5 19.07.2010 1.117,45
6 19.07.2010 1.129,74")
```

====================================================================

### Step 1: Check the data

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Datum  : Factor w/ 1 level "19.07.2010": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Schluss: Factor w/ 6 levels "1.088,38","1.089,31",..: 2 3 1 4 5 6
```

**Okay, we have factors as specified.**

====================================================================

### Step 2: Convert the date column

```
# Read Datum as a date in the specified format and put it back into df.
# %d = day of the month
# %m = month
# %Y = year
# Don't forget the points between the numbers as we have them in the data.
df$Datum <- as.Date(df$Datum, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Check the data again:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Datum  : Date, format: "2010-07-19" ...
 $ Schluss: Factor w/ 6 levels "1.088,38","1.089,31",..: 2 3 1 4 5 6
```

**Okay, now we have dates!**

====================================================================

### Step 3: Convert the number column

```
# Remove the 1000's marks
df$Schluss <- gsub("\\.", "", df$Schluss)
# Change decimal commas into points
df$Schluss <- gsub("\\,", "\\.", df$Schluss)
# Convert into numeric
df$Schluss <- as.numeric(df$Schluss)
```

Check the data again:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Datum  : Date, format: "2010-07-19" ...
 $ Schluss: num  1089 1094 1088 1110 1117 ...
```

**Now they are numeric!

This view does not show the numbers after the decimal point, but don't worry, they are still there.**

====================================================================

### Step 3: Result

```
> df
       Datum Schluss
1 2010-07-19 1089.31
2 2010-07-19 1093.51
3 2010-07-19 1088.38
4 2010-07-19 1110.10
5 2010-07-19 1117.45
6 2010-07-19 1129.74
```

**Does not look terribly different, but now you can use this data for further calculations and transformations.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation